# SQL function table interpolation

Tags: sql, sqlite, interpolation

I have an SQL table of (x,y) values.

```
x     y
0.0   0.0
0.1   0.4
0.5   1.0
5.0   2.0
6.0   4.0
8.0   4.0
10.0  5.0
```

The x column is indexed. I am using sqlite.

My ultimate goal is to get a y(x) for any x value. I will use linear interpolation using table values. Similar as shown in the plot below.

[image]

Is there a way to perform the linear interpolation directly using a select query?
Otherwise getting the interval values where the x belongs, would be enough.

Is there a query that will give me the last smaller and the first bigger pair of a given x, so that I can compute the interpolated y(x) value?

For example if `x=2.0` to get:

```
0.5   1.0
5.0   2.0
```

In case x is out of the table to get the two first/last values to perform an extrapolation.

For example if `x=20.0` to get:

```
8.0   4.0
10.0  5.0
```

Comment: What is your question? How to get the y values, or how to interpolate?

Comment: @CL, both or whatever is possible. If interpolation is not possible, getting the two pairs is enough.

Comment: @CL I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Dear, you have written examples for x = 2 and x = 20 but in your data set are not present. Can you integrate your data set?

Comment: @JoeTaras I think You have missed his point here... ;)
But if I am not missing something, for x=2.0, the returned pair should be: ((0.5,1.0),(5.0,2.0))... right?

Comment: @JoeTaras the examples extract the rows from the table in the beginning of the question

Comment: @JoeTaras I just noticed my x=2.0 example was wrong. I fixed it in the question

Comment: T.Z. / ztik: Ok ok my fault, thanks for explanation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be hard to do this in plain SQLLite, without analytical functions. In more complex SQL engines, You could use [LEG and LEAD](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-window-functions/#lag-and-lead) analytical functions for obtaining set of pairs You want easily enough.
In SQLLite though, I would create two cursors, like those:

Cursor C1:

```
SELECT 
    x,y
FROM
    table
WHERE
    x>=2
ORDER BY
    x asc
;
```

Cursor C2:

```
SELECT 
    x,y
FROM
    table
WHERE
    x<=2
ORDER BY
    x desc
;
```

And perform rest of operations in other language - fetching once from both, or if one cursor do not return value, twice from the other. Also, some additional exceptions need to be handled - what if Your set have less than two values. Or if You have given X in Your set - You do not need interpolata at all... And so on.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to have this in one select. Is this possible?

Comment: I also do not see point (or any simple solution) to this requirement. In X is indexed, fetching from these cursors should be sanly fast.

Comment: I was thinking about speed. If the table is big then getting the pair with one query will reduce time

Comment: It depends on query You need to build to fetch these two pairs at once. I do not think it would be much faster (I think it can be slower in reality in SQLite), and it certainly would be very hard to read, understand and maintain. KISS. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a simple substraction.

You are looking to the two nearest input so :

```
SELECT x, y 
FROM my_table
ORDER BY Abs(:val - x)
LIMIT 2
```

However this will lead to a full table scan.

Comment: Nice thinking. But he still needs a some logic in his app to check if this should be interpolation or extrapolation, and to check if he needs to do anything at all, and so on. And full table scan do not sounds good in terms of preformance. ;) But it is certailny simple and beautifull solution!

Comment: Well the table scan isn't per se a problem. It can be a problem if the table is "big" for the resource aviable. Now we do not know the exact structure of the table, nor if there's another selective column (like graph_id) that would lead to not do a full scan or no

Comment: I have thought of this solution. My main concern is that it does not give always the correct interval. For example if `x=0.6` then I will get 0.1 and 0.5 rows

Comment: Yes, you are right. It just give the two first nearest point. Not the 1st after and the 1st before if avaible